# ValueAnimator duration is not being set

Tags: java, android, animation

I'm trying to reproduce [this iOS-like Bounce Effect](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/80602737edcb2a6431b869b4cc7e7c27db4b60de/687474703a2f2f7777312e73696e61696d672e636e2f6c617267652f3730343839353631677731656a64736a776561657367323038633065706864752e676966) from [this library](https://github.com/coderkiss/BounceScroller).

When I release from touching the `RelativeLayout`, it returns instantaneously to the top when it should bounce back with a *duration* of `n` milliseconds instead.

### Bounce Animation Class

```
public class Bouncer implements AnimatorUpdateListener, AnimatorListener {

        private ValueAnimator mAnimator;
        private int mLastOffset;
        private boolean isHeader;
        private State mTargetState;
        private boolean mCanceled;

        public void recover(boolean header, int offset, State state) {
            cancel();
            Log.d(TAG, "recover offset " + offset);
            mCanceled = false;
            isHeader = header;
            mTargetState = state;
            mAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
            mAnimator.setIntValues(0, offset);
            mLastOffset = 0;
            mAnimator.setRepeatCount(0);
            if (mInterpolator == null) {
                mInterpolator = new DecelerateInterpolator();
            }
            mAnimator.setInterpolator(mInterpolator);
            mAnimator.addListener(this);
            mAnimator.addUpdateListener(this);
            mAnimator.setDuration((long) 1000).start();
        }

        public void cancel() {
            if (mAnimator != null && mAnimator.isRunning()) {
                mAnimator.cancel();
            }
            mAnimator = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator va) {
            int currentOffset = (Integer) va.getAnimatedValue();
            int delta = mLastOffset - currentOffset;
            Log.d(TAG, "recover delta " + delta + " currentOffset "
                    + currentOffset);
            offsetContent(delta);
            mLastOffset = currentOffset;

            if (mListener != null) {
                int contentOffset = mContentView.getTop();
                mListener.onOffset(isHeader, contentOffset);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationEnd");
            mAnimator = null;
            if (!mCanceled) {
                setState(isHeader, mTargetState);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationCancel");
            mCanceled = true;
        }
    }
```

This is where we should be able to change the animation duration:

```
mAnimator.setDuration((long) 1000)
```

But this line doesn't make any difference at all.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you try writing "mAnimator.setDuration(1000);"? (without writing long) Also be aware that 1000 means 1 second. To make sure it's working or not try for example once with 5000 and once with 1000 and see if there is any difference in time.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of it, I did some debugging before asking on SO. However, it doesn't make any changes. Even setting a very high value, `mDuration` still `0` on it's `ValueAnimator` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply going back to the [original commited](https://github.com/coderkiss/BounceScroller/blob/d20ab1ca4e0a52ee844151e7d3e0140e6c359d96/src/me/dawson/bounce/BounceScroller.java) class from the library has solved my issue.

It was a working `Canvas` animation before, I have no idea why they have changed it to `ValueAnimator`.